# extra/locale/locale_mmap.h:46: error: '__LOCALE_DATA_WCctype_II_LEN' undeclared here (not in a function)

Tags: linux, embedded, locale

When I Compile a toolchain  (uClibc) , and get error below:

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Intel-Puma-Toolchain_01/buildroot-2011.
ain/uClibc-0.9.32'
  HOSTCC extra/locale/gen_ldc
In file included from extra/locale/gen_ldc.c:45:
extra/locale/locale_mmap.h:46: error: '__LOCALE_DATA_WCctype_II_LEN' undeclared
unction)
extra/locale/locale_mmap.h:46: error: '__LOCALE_DATA_WCctype_TI_LEN' undeclared
unction)

I have search in google, and found this page 
http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=Ubuntu/Debian_installation_prerequisites#Debian

Maybe my locale has some error, but I have followed this page and changed my locales, these errors are still exist.
 this is my locales, and my OS is debian squeeze

```
xxx@debian:~/Intel-Puma-Toolchain_01$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
xxxx@debian:~/Intel-Puma-Toolchain_01$ locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Do some of you have encountered this errors ,how to fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit your uClibc config file in the `toolchain/uClibc/uClibc-0.9.33.config` directory, and make these change:

```
189,190c189,191
< # UCLIBC_HAS_WCHAR is not set
< # UCLIBC_HAS_LOCALE is not set
---
> UCLIBC_HAS_WCHAR=y
> UCLIBC_HAS_LOCALE=y
> UCLIBC_BUILD_ALL_LOCALE=y
```

clean up uClibc and rebuild again.

```
cd output/toolchain/uClibc-0.9.33.2; make clean; cd ../../..; make
```

`uClibc` will build the Locale data `output/toolchain/uClibc-0.9.33.2/extra/locale/wctables.h`
it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be experiencing this bug:

http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2015-March/048852.html

which causes silent failure to generate `wctables.h`, which is where the missing macro should be defined. Running `./extra/locale/gen_wctype -v en_US` or similar will show any errors that might be occurring generating this file.